# Xfce Compiz doesn't start on first login

Tags: xfce, compiz

I installed Xfce4, Compiz and lxdm on my desktop computer running openSUSE 12.1. To start Compiz as the default WM I edited *~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml* and set

```
<property name="Client0_Command" type="array">
    <value type="string" value="compiz"/>
    <value type="string" value="ccp"/>
</property>
```

But when I login the first time after booting nothing happens. I have to relogin or start compiz via console and everything is fine. When I use the `--debug` flag with Compiz and log the output I **always (even if the start fails)** get

```
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libcore.so :   No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /usr/lib/compiz/libcore.so : No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libccp.so : No such file or directory
Backend     : ini
Integration : true
Profile     : default
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libcomposite.so : No such file or directory
Initializing composite options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libopengl.so : No such file or directory
Initializing opengl options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libdecor.so : No such file or directory
Initializing decor options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libcommands.so : No such file or directory
Initializing commands options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libresize.so : No such file or directory
Initializing resize options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libmove.so : No such file or directory
Initializing move options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libregex.so : No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libgrid.so : No such file or directory
Initializing grid options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libshift.so : No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'text' not loaded.
compiz (shift) - Warn: No compatible text plugin loaded
Initializing shift options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libwobbly.so : No such file or directory
Initializing wobbly options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libmousepoll.so : No such file or directory
Initializing mousepoll options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libcube.so : No such file or directory
Initializing cube options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libthumbnail.so : No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'text' not loaded.
Initializing thumbnail options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/librotate.so : No such file or directory
Initializing rotate options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: Could not stat() file /home/peep/.compiz-1/plugins/libanimation.so : No such file or directory
Initializing animation options...done
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0xe00071
```

By the way, xfwm4 runs without any problems and compiz runs under LXDE, too.

Comment: Of course
`compiz compiz-branding-openSUSE compiz-gnome compiz-lang compiz-plugins-extra compiz-plugins-main compizconfig-settings-manager libcompizconfig python-compizconfig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. I just created a new user, configured the whole thing and somehow it worked. :weird: